# Swift - Call AviewController method from BviewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, methods, uiviewcontroller

I have two viewControllers (AviewController & BviewController ) connected without using segue.
In AviewController i have a UIScrollview.

What I am trying to do is to call a function from BviewController that will disable scrollView in AviewController ( AviewController.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false )

How could I do that without using segue?

BviewController:

```
var AV = AviewController ()

func disable_AscrollView (){
         AviewController.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the code you described doesn't work because the `AV` is not the same instance of `AviewController` as the one which is showing on the screen.

There are several options to get the correct instance, it depends on the situation which one is the best.

1. <s>If you're sure there is only one `AviewController` in your whole app, you can declare a `static var sharedInstance: AviewController`, and set this variable to `self` in the `viewDidLoad` function. Now, from *everywhere* in your app, you can refer to this as `AviewController.sharedInstance` and call its functions, e.g. a custom `disableScrollView` function.</s> (This doesn't seem to work well with Swift, see comments.)
2. If the `AviewController` has a fixed position in the view hierarchy, you can find it via the `window` property of your application delegate, e.g.

   ```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window.rootViewController
   ```

   The root view controller might be a `UINavigationController` in which case you have to dig deeper.
3. Use `NSNotificationCenter`. In the `viewDidLoad` of `AviewController`, register for notifications:

   ```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
       selector: "disableScrollView:",
       name: "DisableScrollView",
       object: nil)
   ```

   Implement the `disableScrollView` function (with `@objc` to use it as a selector):

   ```
   @objc func disableScrollView(notification: NSNotification) {
       // do something
   }
   ```

   When the scroll view needs to be disabled, you can just call

   ```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
       "DisableScrollView", object: nil)
   ```

   from `BviewController`.

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel, AviewController is the only one in the app however, if I use static var sharedInstance: ViewController  I get an error saying: class var declaration requires an initialiser....

Comment: Can you set `nil` as an initial value for the static var?

Comment: adding 'static var sharedInstance: ViewController = nil ' gives me an error : does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

Comment: OK - then this is more difficult to pull off with Swift than I thought. Perhaps using `NSNotificationCenter` is a simpler option, then.

Comment: I was looking at NSNotificationCenter however, cannot find how to send it between viewControillers

Answer (score 0):

If your AViewController is just init, you can modify its attribute between init and push/present method.

If AViewController is already pushed/presented but not at the top of view controller layer(like pushing BViewController in AViewController), you can try delegate or notification.

Set BViewController's delegate as AViewController, you can use `self.delegate?.disableScrollInAViewController()` in BViewController that is implemented by AViewController.

Or just register a notification in AViewController, and post the notification in BViewController.

Comment: How can I register a notification in swift?

Comment: @SNos use `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodYouWantToPerform:", name: "yourNotificationName", object: nil)`